# Osirix for iPad

Tags: ipad

We need to create a plugin for the Osirix application on the iPad. Where shall we get the code base?. The code base for Mac is available on the http://www.osirix-viewer.com/ site. How to convert this to build on iPad?

Answer (score 2):

Facts:

- The iOS version of OsiriX is not open source.
- You cannot create plugins for iOS apps.